# Split an equation into its terms

Tags: maxima

How can I split an equation in Maxima into the separate terms? For example, I would like the equation
`eq1:F=a*b+c*d+g;` to be split into the terms `F`, `a*b`, `c*d`, `g`. Ideally the separate terms should be contained in a list.

Comment: `lhs(eq1)` and `rhs(eq1)` are the left-hand and right-hand side of the equation. For a `+` expression, `args(e)` is the list of addends, where `e` is the `+` expression. (`args` returns the list of operands for any operator.) Maybe you can say more about what you need to do.

Comment: I am using Maxima in STACK (a system to mark answers submitted by students). I would like the system to show the students which of the terms in their answer is correct. For example, of the correct answer is `ta1:F=a*b-c+g` and the student's answer is `sa1:F=a*b+h+g`, then I would like to display the correct terms `F`, `g`, `a*b`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. As a Maxima developer, it's interesting to me that Maxima seems to be used in some different systems for generating and scoring problems. You can let me know if the suggestions I made work for you or if something more is needed.

Comment: Your suggestion works, thanks!